# How to scroll a tkinter canvas to an absolute position?

Tags: python, scroll, tkinter-canvas

I'm using *Python* and *tkinter*. I have a `Canvas` widget that will display just one image. Most times the image will be larger than the canvas dimensions, but sometimes it will be smaller. Let's just focus on the first case (image larger than canvas).

I want to scroll the canvas to an absolute position that I have already calculated (in pixels). How can I do that?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

After trying for around half hour, I got another solution that seems better:

```
self.canvas.xview_moveto(float(scroll_x+1)/img_width)
self.canvas.yview_moveto(float(scroll_y+1)/img_height)
```

- `img_width` and `img_height` are the dimensions of the image. In other words, they are the full scrollable area.
- `scroll_x` and `scroll_y` are the coordinates of the desired top-left corner.
- `+1` is a *magic* value to make it work precisely (but should be applied only if `scroll_x/y` is non-negative)
- Note that the current widget dimension is not needed, only the dimension of the contents.

This solution works very well even if the image is smaller than the widget size (and thus the `scroll_x/y` can be negative).

EDIT: improved version:

```
offset_x = +1 if scroll_x >= 0 else 0
offset_y = +1 if scroll_y >= 0 else 0
self.canvas.xview_moveto(float(scroll_x + offset_x)/new_width)
self.canvas.yview_moveto(float(scroll_y + offset_y)/new_height)
```

Comment: Use vertical_scrollbar.set(y0,y1) to apply the changes in the scrollbar.

Answer (score 0):

This is what I have already done:

```
# Little hack to scroll by 1-pixel increments.
oldincx = self.canvas["xscrollincrement"]
oldincy = self.canvas["yscrollincrement"]
self.canvas["xscrollincrement"] = 1
self.canvas["yscrollincrement"] = 1
self.canvas.xview_moveto(0.0)
self.canvas.yview_moveto(0.0)
self.canvas.xview_scroll(int(scroll_x)+1, UNITS)
self.canvas.yview_scroll(int(scroll_y)+1, UNITS)
self.canvas["xscrollincrement"] = oldincx
self.canvas["yscrollincrement"] = oldincy
```

But... As you can see... it's very hackish and ugly. To much workaround for something that should be simple. (plus that magic `+1` I was required to add, or it would be off-by-one)

Does anyone else have another better and cleaner solution?

Answer (score 0):

In tkinter you can get the `width` and `height` of a `PhotoImage`file. You can just call it when you use `canvas.create_image`

```
imgrender = PhotoImage(file="something.png")
##Other canvas and scrollbar codes here...
canvas.create_image((imgrender.width()/2),(imgrender.height()/2), image=imgrender)
## The top left corner coordinates is (width/2 , height/2)
```

Answer (score 0):

I found this solution by using `self.canvas.scan_dragto(x, y)`

Edit: I develop an interface which can scroll, zoom, and rotate an image. Let's extract from my interface the code.

When I want to save the current position of image I use this:

```py
# 1) Save image position
x0canvas = -self.canvas.canvasx(0)
y0canvas = -self.canvas.canvasy(0)
x0, y0 = self.canvas.coords(text)
ximg = x0
yimg = y0

# 2) Restore image position (for example: after a load)
self.text = canvas.create_text(ximg, yimg, anchor='nw', text='')
self.xyscroll(x0canvas, y0canvas) 

# Rotate and zoom image 
image = Image.open('fileImg.jpg')
..
imageMod = image.resize(new_size)
if rotate != 0:
    imageMod = imageMod.rotate(rotate)
imagetk = ImageTk.PhotoImage(imageMod)
imageid = canvas.create_image(canvas.coords(text), anchor='nw', image=imagetk)
```